# SCP to deny all resources except certain resources in AWS Organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-policies

I want to block all resources except EC2, RDS and global services in AWS Organization. Below is my SCP Policy.

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
  "Sid": "DenyAllOutsideEU",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "NotAction": [
    "iam:*",
    "cloudfront:*",
    "route53:*",
    "route53domains:*",
    "s3:GetAccountPublic*",
    "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
    "s3:PutAccountPublic*",
    "shield:*",
    "sts:*",
    "support:*",
    "trustedadvisor:*",
    "waf-regional:*",
    "waf:*",
    "wafv2:*",
    "wellarchitected:*"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {
      "aws:RequestedRegion": [
        "ap-south-1"
      ]
    },
    "ArnNotLike": {
      "aws:PrincipalARN": [
        "arn:aws:iam::*:role/Role1AllowedToBypassThisSCP",
        "arn:aws:iam::*:role/Role2AllowedToBypassThisSCP"
      ]
    }
  }
}
]
}
```

Using this policy, I'm not able to get full access to WAF. Below is WAF service access denied error screen shot.

[image]

Can any one please help me to achieve this?

Comment: Does the IAM User have permission (from IAM) to use WAF? It might not be the Deny causing the problem, it might be because they are not Allowed to use it. To test: If you remove this SCP policy, can they access WAF?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to access WAF by removing the SCP policy. I have IAM Administration access so it seems the SCP policy is blocking my access

Comment: Since it is a Deny policy and it includes `NotAction: wafv2:*`, then it would seem that the page you have shown is trying to call an API that is _not_ part of WAF. You might want to look at CloudTrail to see what Action was blocked.

Comment: there is no API calls in CloudTrail. Is there any policy for my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is `ec2:DescribeRegions`.

You already have all the access you want. If you try through aws cli you can do whatever you have allowed in the policy. However `Web ACLs` page in AWS console has a dropdown to load all AWS regions which uses the `ec2:DescribeRegions` api call and if you don't have it you can't open the page.
You have two options. Either add the missing permission to your policy. Or if you don't want to add that you can add `region=ap-south-1` to your URL in the browser every time you navigate to WAF page.

Also I suggest you to look into `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSWAFConsoleFullAccess`. There are other permissions you might need. For example if you want to associate a web-acl to a Load Balancer you will need `elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers` and `elasticloadbalancing:SetWebACL`.